# Segmentation fault when trying to set a dereferenced pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

This code raises segmentation fault on the last line. Header is a pointer to a contiguous block of memory which is all 0, and dereferencing the remainder returns 0 which is probably related to the issue. I still feel like this should work though, what is the issue?

```
void setHeader(void *header, size_t payload) {
   size_t *remainder = (size_t*)((char *)header + (payload + 4));
   *remainder = payload;
}
```

Comment: How are you allocating header and what's payload?

Comment: This code is for a memory allocator. Header is the pointer returned from a function provided called ExtendHeapSegment, which extends the size of the heap and returns the head of the new memory block. I am not sure of the actual contents/logistics of this block but it comes from whatever Kernel process extends the heap (don't know the details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think this should work? Unless the pointed-to object is sufficiently large that adding `payload + 4` does not exceed the size of the object, the pointer arithmetic has undefined behavior. Even if the arithmetic is defined (e.g. if the object size is exactly `payload + 4`), dereferencing the slot one past the end of an array has UB. You'll need to make sure the object whose address you're passing is sufficiently large in order for your code to work.

Comment: Ahh, found the issue elsewhere along these lines. The memory is of the right size but we were handling the offset for a header block incorrectly. Thank you.